# How to create method of alert dialog with parameter for buttons?

Tags: android

I want something like this. I want to reuse my alert dialog method but I do not know how can I implement a parameter for positive and negative buttons:

```
private void alert(String title, String message, actionPositive, actionNegative){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionProfile.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //action
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

And I want to call that something like this it is possible ?

```
alert("Title","Message",action for positive button, action for negative button);
```

Comment: what action you want perform on positive and negative button

Comment: for example I can use positive for add and negative for cancel and I can also use it for other features such as positive for delete and negative for cancel and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as simple as following:

```
private void alert(String title, String message,DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionPositive, DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionNegative){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionProfile.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",actionPositive);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",actionNegative);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Sample usage with anonymous class would be:

```
alert("Title","Message",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //action for positive
                }
            }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //action for negative
                }
            });
```

Comment: how about when I want to call the method how should I set what I want with the buttons ? can you give an example ? thank you

Comment: @AngeloLucena great! remember to mark answer as accepted if it was useful, so that others can benefit too

Comment: @AngeloLucena click on the tick style button located under upvote/downvote arrows. It must be grey and will turn green once you do that

Answer (score 1):

You can do It wither using int case set or `boolean`.  If `boolean` is `true` then it will show delete and if `false` it will show OK  as follows -

```
private void alert(String title, String message, boolean actionPositive, boolean actionNegative){
String positive = ""; 
 if(actionPositive)
       positive = "DELETE"
 else 
       positive = "OK"

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionProfile.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton(positive,   //give name to your action
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     if(actionPositive)
                         //action delete 
                     else 
                         //action ok
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

In above mention way you can use for negative button also.

your method call for delete will be as follows

```
alert(""title, "message", true, false)
```

and for ok

```
alert(""title, "message", false, false)
```

Comment: @Angelo Lucena you can try this approach as well.  this approach is for managing multiple case and action.